# Найти файл по Uri (java android)

Tags: java, android, файлы

Пользователь выбирает файл, я получаю его android.net.Uri:

```
public void onActivityResult (int req, int res, Intent intent) {
    if (res != RESULT_OK) return;
    if (req == FILE_SELECT_CODE) {
        Uri uri = intent.getData();

    }
}
```

Каким образом мне из этого Uri получить сам файл, доступный для считывания?

Comment: File file = new File(uri.getPath())?

Comment: Спасибо, вроде как работает. Просто getPath() возвращал что-то странное, поэтому не думал, что это верный способ.

Comment: Хотя нет, не работает, объект File создает, однако самого такого файла не существует

Answer (score 0):

Таким образом можно получить путь к файлу из `Uri`, если `Uri` это ссылка на изображение

```
    public static String getRealImagePathFromUri(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Не могли бы Вы в 2 словах пояснить, что этот код конкретно делает?

Comment: Я знаю, что этот код делает :)

Comment: а если uri - ссылка на обычный файл? Я пытался через MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.Data, но не получилось

Comment: @abextra только что столкнулся с этой проблемой
Если запрашивать изображение из галерии приходит uri типа content://media/external/images/media/4627 и его можно преобразовать в файл при помощи функции из ответа

Если запросить из файлового менеджера file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/1495629327357.jpg , такой Uri уже напрямую можно преобразовать в файл new File(uri.getPath())